# Run script on orientation change

Tags: javascript

Want to run a script that gets the width of the page and resizes a div to fit. The only problem was orientation on iPad when it changed it didn't update. The first parts works fine,

```
function getWidth() {
var w = window.innerWidth;
x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.style.width= w +"px"; 
}
```

Want to add it into this,

```
function doOnOrientationChange()
{
switch(window.orientation) 
{  
  case -90:
  case 90:
    alert('landscape');
    break; 
  default:
    alert('portrait');
    break; 
}
}
```

but change the alert to the getWidth function but can get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind on the `orientationchange` event, like so:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", doOnOrientationChange, false);
```

or in jQuery

```
$(window).on("orientationchange", doOnOrientationChange);
```